Retrieving Business Rules from IBM WebSphere via CLI
Like the title states, I am searching for a way to retrieve Business Rules from the CLI.
I would like to make a script to automate Business Rules exports, so everything has to run through the terminal. Is there a way to export the Business Rules through the terminal?
